# How can I get interpreted values (ex concat) of an azure arm templates in powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell, templates

We are using ARM templates to deploy resources in Azure tenant.
In the templates, we have made some variables expressions like this one

```
  "rscPrefix": "[concat(parameters('regionCode'),parameters('entity'))]"
```

When the templates are sent to the Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment or New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment, the substitutions of these json expressions are working perfectly.

My problem is to retrieve the interpreted values in powershell to launch additional azure command that can not be done in arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are launching the template you can parse the parameters file or just use the same input in your powershell to calculate those, an alternative would be to use template outputs to output those values and read them with powershell:

```
Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name zzz
```

and you'll have all the outputs under the outputs property.

Comment: It is exactly what I have done. I also have found that azure process the file even if the resources section is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done.
The company for wich I work have conventions for the naming of objects.
The formulas to get these names are in the arm templates and I did not wanted to implement another piece of code in powershell to redo these formulas.

So I have created an arm template file with empty resources.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": { 
    "regionCode": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "we"
    },
    "entity": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "cdo"
    },
    "environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "stag",
        "allowedValues": [
            "dev",
            "test",
            "stag",
            "prod"
        ]
    },
     "plateform": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "hub"
    }

},
"variables": {
    "rscPrefix": "[concat(parameters('regionCode'),parameters('entity'))]",
    "cosmosDB": "[concat(variables('rscPrefix'),'cdb',parameters('environment'),parameters('plateform'))]"
    },

"resources": [],
"outputs": {
    "cosmosDB": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[variables('cosmosDB')]"
    }
}
```

}

To get the outputs :

```
  $paramsOutputJson= az group deployment create --name "AzConfiguration" --resource-group "YourGroupName" --template-file "$templateFilePath" --parameters "$parametersFilePath"
```

I can manipulate this configuration easily in devops and keep some sections identical on multiple arm templates and use the same configuration with powershell commands.